# Android run time errors

Tags: android, android-gridview

I wonder if any one can help me, I'm writing an android program and whenever I run the emulator, these errors show up:

```
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gridviewexample/com.example.gridviewexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gridviewexample.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gridviewexample-2.apk
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gridviewexample.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gridviewexample-2.apk
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-24 15:06:17.464: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  ... 11 more
```

I'm trying to write a grid view code, I would really appreciate it if anyone could help, thanks a lot :)

Comment: ClassNotFoundException is the meaningful part. Read those lines. Also, those aren't multiple errors. It's the stack trace for one error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declared your activity `com.example.gridviewexample.MainActivity` in your [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

Also, make sure that your `MainActivity` has the correct package name set in the top of the file (e.g *`package com.example.gridviewexample`*).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help :) But I also have another question and would really appreciate your help again, if I would like to make 2 boards in the same activity that's 10*10 each, and I want to fill the cells with the same image, such that there are 200 images of the same one, how could I do that? do I make an array that has these 200 images in the imageAdapter class?

Comment: Well I mean that I want to make 2 boards, each board is 10*10 (10 rows by 10 columns), and I want to fill the 2 boards with a single image (all the cells have the same image), how would I do that using grid view?

Comment: As @seb said, create a new thread for your question. Someone might give you a better answer which will be properly referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The system cannot find the **MainActivity.class** in your com.example.gridviewexample package.

Take a look to see if you have such a class in there.

A Project -> Clean could also help(provided you're using Eclipse).

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project.

Comment: I'm kind of new to the site, and I want to add your reputation, how can I do that? haha

Comment: On the left of the post you have a number with 2 arrows and a check mark. Selecting the check mark means you have accepted the answer as the solution. You can also vote-up or down the answer by using the arrows.

Comment: Also, a piece of advice. I see that you are asking additional questions in comments. Try to create a new question instead of asking it in the chat. A lot more useful and it can contribute to the community as well.